# Showing Silverlight unit tests in VS2013 Test Explorer

Tags: unit-testing, silverlight, mvvm, visual-studio-2013

I have a Silverlight client project `Project.Client` employing strong use of MVVM with Caliburn Micro, however there's lots of calculations in the ViewModels that I see fit to unit test.

I would like to create a `Project.Client.Test` unit test project which references `Project.Client` and have its test results appear in Test Explorer *(and not test results showing in a web page)*.

I installed NUnit 3 with the runners and adapters however I cannot see unit tests in Visual Studio 2013's Test Explorer. Is there a way to do that?